# ¿Cómo hacer una petición get varias veces en android?

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación android que recibe una url donde se encuentra un archivo json.
La aplicación una vez que tiene la url

```
    direccion/carpeta/carpeta2/result.json
```

se va inmediatamente a ese lugar pero puede que el archivo json aun no se encuentre lleno y se ve así:

```
    {"height":720,"width":720,"captions":[],"boxes":[]}
```

Así que tengo que hacer la petición get o recarcargar de nuevo hasta que salga lleno el archivo json

o sea así:

```
    {"height":375,"width":500,
    "captions":["wooden cabinets kitchen",
    "brown cabinets in kitchen","a black and white stove",
    "the floor is wooden","window with white frame",
    "a kitchen with white and black stove",
    "wooden cabinets in kitchen","window with white blinds",
    "window in the room","a kitchen with white walls",
    "a white window frame","a wooden headboard","a wooden floor",
    "the cabinet is made of wood","a brown cabinet",
    "brown wooden cabinets"],
    "boxes":[[60.355659484863],[288.16293334961],
    [352.76892089844],[288.03231811523],
    [208.66075134277]]}
```

y eso es lo que no se hacer...

¿Cómo hago la petición otra vez?

este es mi código para hacer el get

```
    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); //Obtenemos el JSON global
                JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("captions"); //Obtenemos el array captions
                for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) //Miramos en todos los objetos del array
                    textView.setText(jArray.toString());
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿De que depende que el json no esté lleno?

Comment: ¿Con cuál lenguaje se trabaja del lado del servidor?

Comment: se usa un servidor que primero recibe un post... el servidor recibiendo post te manda la url pero el servidor aún está procesando el post y mientras no acabe el json no puede estar lleno

Comment: si, pero ¿cuál lenguaje?

Comment: del lado del servidor es phyton

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes creado tu `AsyncTask` el cual recibe un url que es el .json a parsear, simplemente puedes llamar ejecutar al `AsyncTask` de acuerdo a los url que necesitas parser:

```
 new JSONTask().execute("http://mydomain.com/archivo1.json");
 new JSONTask().execute("http://mydomain.com/archivo2.json");
 new JSONTask().execute("http://mydomain.com/archivo3.json");
...
...
```

Otra forma es enviar un varios url y al recibirlos en `doInBackground()` se obtiene un Array que contiene estos valores:

```
new JSONTask().execute(urlJson1, urlJson2, urlJson3);
```

pero dentro de tu `AsyncTask` tendrías que realizar modificaciones realizar las peticiones de este Array de urls:

```
class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject[]> {
     ...
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


         String urlJson1 = params[0];
         String urlJson2 = params[1];
         String urlJson3 = params[2];

    ...
    ...
```